# Get screenshot of all monitors android

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, screenshot

Problem: 
I want to take a screenshot from a multi monitor setup on android.

For example if you have a chromebook an external monitor can be attached.

How other screen capture applications seem to work is to use MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), however it let the user choose a specific screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please remark that a potential solution does not have to use MediaProjectionManager

Comment: Still have no solution for this question

Comment: Hi @lassealm2 : Are you able to find any solution? I am trying to implement a similar kind of functionality.